# How to declare a function with N arguments of type double?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

I would like to have a class template capable of storing a functional object accepting exactly "N" double arguments. This pseudo-code uses a non-existing `std::repeated_type` function template that would solve the problem and illustrates the intended usage:

```cpp
template<int N>
class FunctionHolder {
public:
   using function_type = std::function<int(std::repeated_type<double, N> args)>;
   FunctionHolder(const function_type& arg): m_func(arg) {}
private:
   const function_type& m_func;
};

int my_func(double arg1, double arg2);

void main() {
   FunctionHolder<2> my_holder(my_func);  
}
```

I want the code to be maximally simple and readable, so even though
I vaguely understand I can stitch a solution using a std::integer_sequence and helper class templates, but I don't feel confident that my solution would be simple enough.

Comment: What is the underlying problem you need to solve? Why do you think something like the theoretical `std::repeated_type` would solve that problem? If you ask about that problem directly instead, someone might come up with a better solution.

Comment: How about using `std::array<double, N>` as the parameter ?

Comment: *"N" double arguments* is `std::array<double, N>` or `std::initializer_list<double>`.

Comment: Send array or pointer to structure.

Comment: Looks like what you want is https://godbolt.org/z/j9vchqxbx

Comment: @康桓瑋 That really looks like what OP wanted (I'd have just made [it](https://godbolt.org/z/qYo8njxnd) a bit more generic). Would you mind expanding your comment into an answer?

Comment: @Bob__ I don't intend to make this an answer, since both GCC and MSVC seem to be broken by the syntax of such a solution. [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3h84ffdTc)

Comment: @康桓瑋 I really liked your idea. I modified it so it works in gcc, msvc and icx (which also failed before) [here](https://godbolt.org/z/6M74ExYcK). If you'd like to post it, please go ahead. Otherwise I may add that alternative to my answer.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Feel free to add alternates to your answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can recursively add function arguments to a template list:

```
template <typename Ret, std::size_t N, typename Type, typename... T>
struct RepeatFunctionArgType {
    static auto fnt() {
        if constexpr (sizeof...(T) >= N) {
            return std::function<Ret(T...)>{};
        } else {
            return RepeatFunctionArgType<Ret, N, Type, Type, T...>::fnt();
        }
    }
    using type = decltype(fnt());
};
```

This can be accessed as `RepeatFunctionArgType<int,3,double>::type`.

```
static int foo(double,double,double) {return 0;}

int main() {
    RepeatFunctionArgType<int,3,double>::type fn = foo;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You could use a lambda in an unevaluated context to get its return type:

```cpp
using function_type =
    decltype([]<std::size_t... I>(std::index_sequence<I...>) {
        // expand to as many `double`s as there are `I`s:
        return std::function<int(decltype((static_cast<void>(I)), double{})...)>{};
    }(std::make_index_sequence<N>{}));
```

alternatively

```cpp
using function_type =
    decltype([]<std::size_t... I>(std::index_sequence<I...>)
        // expand to as many `double`s as there are `I`s:
        -> std::function<int(decltype((static_cast<void>(I)), double{})...)> {
            // this space intentionally left blank
        }(std::make_index_sequence<N>{}));
```

---

A more generic solution adapted from 康桓瑋's code in the comments could look like this:

```cpp
template <std::size_t, class T>
using identity = T;

template <class R, class Arg, std::size_t N>
struct repeated_arg_func {
    using type =
        typename decltype([]<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
                              -> std::type_identity<R(identity<Is, Arg>...)> {
        }(std::make_index_sequence<N>{}))::type;
};

template <class R, class Arg, std::size_t N>
using repeated_arg_func_t = typename repeated_arg_func<R, Arg, N>::type;

template <int N, class ArgType, class RetType>
class FunctionHolder {
public:
    using signature = repeated_arg_func_t<RetType, ArgType, N>;
    using function_type = std::function<signature>;
    FunctionHolder(const function_type& arg) : m_func(arg) {}

private:
    function_type m_func;
};
```

---

Sidenote: The `const function_type&` member is not a good idea unless you actually supply a`std::function<...>` that outlives your `FunctionHolder`. Your example creates a temporary `std::function<...>` that will expire as soon as the construction of the `FunctionHolder` is done.

I suggest making it a regular non-reference member:

```cpp
function_type m_func;
```

Answer (score 6):

With helper class template, it might be

```
template <std::size_t, typename T>
using always_t = T;

template<typename Seq> class FunctionHolderImpl;

template<std::size_t... Is>
class FunctionHolderImpl<std::index_sequence<Is...>> {
public:
   using function_type = std::function<int(always_t<Is, double>... args)>;

   FunctionHolder(const function_type& arg): m_func(arg) {}
private:
   function_type m_func;
};

template <std::size_t N>
using FunctionHolder = FunctionHolderImpl<std::make_index_sequence<N>>;
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a C++17 solution, where you don't have to specialize the holder explicitly in main(), nor have to explicitly state the number of arguments.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

// Some helpers to check if all arguments of the function have the same argument type
template<typename arg_t, typename... args_t>
static constexpr bool all_same_as_first()
{
    return std::conjunction_v<std::is_same<arg_t, args_t>...>;
};

template<typename... args_t>
static constexpr bool all_same()
{
    // Specialized logic for 0 or 1 argument, consider them the same. 
    if constexpr (sizeof...(args_t) < 2ul)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return all_same_as_first<args_t...>();
    }
}

// The actual function holder
// it also needs specialization on the return value type
template<typename retval_t, typename... args_t>
class FunctionHolder
{
public:
    static_assert(all_same<args_t...>()); // check condition that all arguments are of same type

    // construct
    explicit FunctionHolder(std::function<retval_t(args_t...)> fn) :
        m_fn{ fn }
    {
    }

    // allow calls to be made through the holder directly
    retval_t operator()(args_t&&...args)
    {
        return m_fn(std::forward<args_t>(args)...);
    }

private:
    std::function<retval_t(args_t...)> m_fn;
};

// helper for type deduction of std::function type 
template<typename fn_t>
auto make_holder(fn_t fn)
{
    std::function std_fn{fn};
    return FunctionHolder{ std_fn };
}

// your function
int my_func(double arg1, double arg2)
{
    return static_cast<int>(arg1+arg2);
}

// And the usage
int main()
{
    auto holder = make_holder(my_func);
    auto retval = holder(1.0, 2.0);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

How about sth like this:

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>

template<int N, typename...Args>
struct FunctionHolder {
public:
    using function_type = std::function<int(Args...)>;
    static_assert(sizeof...(Args) == N);
    static_assert((std::is_same_v<Args, double> && ...), "");

    FunctionHolder(const function_type& arg): m_func(arg) {}
    const function_type m_func;
};

template<int N, typename...Args>
auto makeFunctionHolder(int(*f)(Args...))
{
    return FunctionHolder<N, Args...>(f);
}

int my_func(double arg1, double arg2)
{
    return arg1+arg2;
}

int my_func2(double arg1, char arg2)
{
    return arg1+arg2;
}

int my_func3(double arg1)
{
    return arg1;
}

int main() {
    auto h1 = makeFunctionHolder<2>(my_func);
    //auto h2 = makeFunctionHolder<2>(my_func2); //should fail due to types
    // auto h3 = makeFunctionHolder<2>(my_func3); //should fail to number
    auto h3 = makeFunctionHolder<1>(my_func3); //should pass
    return h1.m_func(4.0, 5.0);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/cjEq4s7Ef

Granted, it uses the factory function, but it can possibly be also achieved using deduction guide.
Everything made public just for the sake of testing, adjust it to your liking.

Comment: Extra factory to avoid `<N>`: `template<typename...Args>auto makeFunctionHolder(int(*f)(Args...)) { return FunctionHolder<sizeof...(Args), Args...>(f); }`. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3Yxr4E18W)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`std::array<double, N>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) as the parameter for the functions
(instead of separate `double` parameters):

```
#include <array>
#include <functional>

template<int N>
class FunctionHolder {
public:
    //--------------------------------------vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv--------
    using function_type = std::function<int(std::array<double, N> args)>;
    FunctionHolder(const function_type& arg) : m_func(arg) {}
private:
    const function_type& m_func;
};

//----------vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv-------
int my_func(std::array<double, 2> arg2) {
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    FunctionHolder<2> my_holder(my_func);
}
```

[Demo - Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/s7hddKGE4)

Comment: That solution imposes a different signature on the function. What if I intend to us an `operator*` as a function? I would have to use wrappers around it, hinders readability

Comment: I agree. But since your question did not mention such details, I thought this direction might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make a function with N arguments you could use a feature provided in the [mlib](https://www.github.com/robertshepherdcpp/mlib) library. It looks like this in code:

```cpp
#include<utility>    // std::index_sequence
#include<functional> // std::function

template<typename Type, auto value>
struct always_type_t
{
    using type = Type;
};

template<typename Type, auto value>
using always_type = always_type_t<Type, value>::type;

template<typename returnType, typename argType, auto N>
struct repeatedFunctionArgument
{
    constexpr repeatedFunctionArgument(auto function) {m_function = std::function{function};}
    constexpr returnType callFunction() const noexcept {return m_function();}
    
    using type = decltype(
        []<std::size_t... indexes>(std::index_sequence<indexes...>)
        {
            return std::function<int(always_type<int, indexes>... args)>{};
        }(std::make_index_sequence<N>{})
    );

    type m_function;
};

int main()
{
    repeatedFunctionArgument<int, int, 2> lambda([](int a, int b) -> int {return 0;});
}
```

[Godbolt Link](https://godbolt.org/z/zY39nKP4E)

Answer (score 0):

Using C++11 more old fashioned way (template specialization) of writing templates:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstddef>

template<typename Ret, size_t N, typename T, typename...Args>
struct repeated_fun_argument
{
    using type = typename repeated_fun_argument<Ret, N - 1, T, T, Args...>::type;
};

template<typename Ret, typename T, typename...Args>
struct repeated_fun_argument<Ret, 0, T, Args...>
{
    using type = Ret(Args...);
};

template<typename Ret, size_t N, typename T>
using repeated_fun_argument_t = typename repeated_fun_argument<Ret, N, T>::type;
```

https://godbolt.org/z/98sxWqsr1